# How to set condition to set channel url using setState method in onChannelSelect props of sendbird-uikit package?

Tags: reactjs, sendbird

**onChannelSelect** function is called whenever component is rendered so **channelUrl** variable is reset.Because of that channel url is not changed when we click on any channel.Every time first channel's url was set from channel list.So how can i set channel url using setState method ??

```
import { ChannelList, SendBirdProvider, Channel } from "sendbird-uikit";

 setChannelUrl = (channel) => {
        console.log("channel", channel.url)
        this.setState({ channelUrl: channel.url })

    }
<div className="container cart">
                        <SendBirdProvider appId={global.chat.sendbirdAppId}
                            userId={profile.sendbird_id} >
                            <div className="card card-aspenku">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-md-4" style={{ height: '400px' }} >
                                        <ChannelList
                                            onChannelSelect={(channel) => {
                                                if (this.state.channelUrl === "" || 
                                                    this.state.channelUrl !== channel.url) 
                                                {
                                                    console.log("channel")
                                                    this.setChannelUrl(channel)
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    console.log("no channel")
                                                }
                                            }}
                                            queries={{
                                                channelListQuery: {
                                                    includeEmpty: true,
                                                },
                                                applicationUserListQuery: {
                                                    limit: 30,
                                                    userIdsFilter: [profile.sendbird_id],
                                                }
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-md-8" style={{ height: '400px' }}>
                                        {this.state.channelUrl && <Channel
                                            channelUrl={this.state.channelUrl}
                                            queries={{
                                                messageListParams: {
                                                    senderUserIds: [profile.sendbird_id],
                                                    prevResultSize: 10,
                                                    includeParentMessageText: true,
                                                    includeReaction: true,
                                                }
                                            }}

                                        />}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </SendBirdProvider>
                    </div>
```

Comment: It seems that "this.state.channelUrl.channelUrl === "" ||  this.state.channelUrl.channelUrl !== channel.url " condition goes wrong every time because state value is stored in this state : this state.channelUrl , Not in this state : this state.channelUrl.channelUrl.

Can you verify it first ?

Comment: It was typing mistake.Thanks @mayurkukadiya for inform me about that mistake.

Comment: You should remove condition first and try to call "this.setState({ channelUrl: channel.url })" inside onChannelSelect() instead of calling function. and log that channel.url on click..(this changes should done for debug purpose only)
So I can Identify that clicked url is correct or not !!!. confirm that channel url is not same in all channel according to channelList....

Comment: @mayurkukadiya , "this.setState" directly not working in render.If i will set then it will be go in infinite loop.